# Does Brownie support structs and enums?

Tags: python, brownie, unittesting, vyper, enum

[Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/toctree.html) is a seemingly popular framework for testing smart contracts (both solidity and vyper) in python.

I've just gotten started with brownie and my first few tests are working. However, I can't figure out how to construct structs or enums in brownie's tests in the python code. Is this possible?

The brownie docs don't mention anything about structs or enums in their [Data Types docs](docs https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-types.html) even though both solidity and vyper support them.

- Solidity structs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#structs
- Solidity enums: https://docs.soliditlang.org/en/latest/types.html#enums
- Vyper structs: https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/stable/types.html#structs
- Vyper enums: https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/stable/types.html#enums